# How to declarer a parameter of IO type in Python3?

Tags: python, python-typing

In latest version of Python3, we can declarer the type of a parameter like this:

```
def foo(para1: type1, para2: type2, ...):
```

If I want to let a parameter be of type IO stream, like `file = open('...', 'w')`, how can I write the type?

When I use `open(...)` as a parameter, its type is `typing.TextIO`.

However, if I want to use `sys.stdout`, its type becomes `_io.TextIOWrapper`.

Is there any type for all of this kind?

Comment: `typing.TextIO` seems to [work just fine](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f478986cf5fe751fd01dfc5a1e52e321), have you had a specific problem?

Comment: All right. I was just looking for a more elegant solution. I think I saw `SupportWrite[str]` some time, but that doesn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `SupportsWrite` sounds like the [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/7d33060e6ae3ebe54462a891f0c566c97371915b/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L223) custom protocol. Depending on what you intend to actually _do_ with the object, something like that might make sense. For example, if you don't care about whether it actually inherits from the `typing.IO` ABC or the `io` base classes, but only expect it to have a `write` method that accepts a single `str` argument.

Comment: [Here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=f12a56184ac28539fe9d7de3a73c4978) is an example of an even simpler (non-generic) protocol. It works with both `sys.stdout` and "regular" file-like objects returned by `open`.